# SQL function in ORM

Tags: sql-server, django, django-orm

I have SQL Server, FreeTDS, Django 1.5.5. For SQL Server's full text search, I need to use contains function of Sql server.

This will search "mytext" in my_table's x_name field.

```
select x_name from my_table where contains(x_name, 'mytext')
```

For doing it with ORM, there is djorm-ext-expressions.

http://www.niwi.be/2012/10/07/sqlexpressions-and-functions-with-django/

That works fine if there is only one argument for the sql function, but contains have two: field name and text.

It generates Sql's Where statement like this:

```
MyTable.objects.where(Contains("x_name", "mytext"))
               .query.get_compiler("default").as_sql()
```

Output:

```
WHERE (contains("x_name"))', ('mytext',))
```

But it should output like this:

```
WHERE (contains("x_name", 'mytext'))
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: That looks like a bug in the ORM.

Comment: For this, i am using raw sql but orm would be better and safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem:

```
MyTable.objects.where(RawExpression("contains(x_name, %s)", 'mytext'))
```